# Why subtracting int.MinValue by itself twice results in int.MinValue?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the positive value of a number without using `Math.Abs` like this:

```
int small = -1000;
Console.WriteLine(small - small - small);
int big = int.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine(big - big - big);
```

The first works just fine, I get 1000 printed, but for the second case, it gets `-2147483648` instead of a positive `2147483648`.

I suspected this had to do with integer overflow, but I thought it wouldn't make sense, because the result of the operation shouldn't overflow integer bounds.

For instance:

```
(-2147483648) - (-2147483648) = 0
0 - (-2147483648) = 2147483648
```

or

```
(-2147483648) - (-2147483648) - (-2147483648) = 2147483648
```

What am I missing?

Comment: No....the range of an int is -2147483648 to 2147483647 (not 8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say:

```
(-2147483648) - (-2147483648) = 0
0 - (-2147483648) = 2147483648
```

Mathematically, this works out.  However, `int.MaxValue` is `2147483647`.  `2147483648` is equivalent to `int.MaxValue + 1`, which overflows, wrapping the result back to `-2147483648`.

Comment: Ow, that makes sense, I didn't pay attention the result was actually overflowing `int.MaxValue`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alisson Fun fact: wrap your code in `checked { .... }` and you will get an overflow exception instead.

Comment: @DavidG that's interesting. I'd expect it to happen if I was assigning the result of these operations to an int variable, but I guess this happens because the subtraction/sum of integer values results in an integer value as well (likewise dividing two integer values results in integer). I guess I should convert them to an appropriate type before subtracting them.